# Why does my code not remove letters from available letter

Tags: python

i am trying to make a python hangman game the following code almost does what i need it to but when you guess a letter it removes it from available letters instead it keeps it the same

```
import random

def load_words():
    with open("words.txt", "r") as file:
        words = file.readlines()
    return words

def choose_word(word_list):
    return random.choice(word_list).strip()

def display_word(word, guessed_letters):
    return ' '.join([letter if letter in guessed_letters else '_ ' for letter in word])

def hangman(secret_word):
    guessed_letters = set()
    incorrect_guesses = 0
    max_incorrect_guesses = 8

    print("Welcome to the game Hangman!")
    print("I am thinking of a word that is {} letters long.".format(len(secret_word)))

    while incorrect_guesses < max_incorrect_guesses:
        print("-------------")
        print("You have {} guesses left.".format(max_incorrect_guesses - incorrect_guesses))

        available_letters = ''.join([letter if letter not in guessed_letters else '' for letter in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'])
        print("Available letters: {}".format(available_letters))

        guess = input("Please guess a letter: ").lower()

        if guess in guessed_letters:
            print("Oops! You've already guessed that letter: {}".format(display_word(secret_word, guessed_letters)))
        elif guess in secret_word:
            guessed_letters.add(guess)
            print("Good guess: {}".format(display_word(secret_word, guessed_letters)))
        else:
            incorrect_guesses += 1
            print("Oops! That letter is not in my word: {}".format(display_word(secret_word, guessed_letters)))

        if all(letter in guessed_letters for letter in secret_word):
            print("-------------")
            print("Congratulations, you won!")
            break

    if incorrect_guesses == max_incorrect_guesses:
        print("-------------")
        print("Sorry, you ran out of guesses. The word was {}.".format(secret_word))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    word_list = load_words()
    secret_word = choose_word(word_list)
    hangman(secret_word)
```

it doesnt remove letter like if the word is car and you guess b it will show abcdefghikjlmnopqrstuvwxyz instead of acdefghikjlmnopqrstuvwxyz

Answer (score 3):

In your else statement you still need to add letter to guessed_letters even if it's incorrect. You're not doing that right now, only when it is a correct letter.

```py
 else:
   incorrect_guesses += 1
   guessed_letters.add(guess)
   print("Oops! That letter is not in my word 
   {}".format(display_word(secret_word, guessed_letters)))
```

Comment: now when I run it it prints: That letter is not in my word_  ***